# c++ linked list(tree) delete computation speed issue

Tags: c++, tree, linked-list

My code works fine, but I have an issue with computation speed. My code consists of array and list(tree) When I dont remove(delete) and keep all the data, the calculation time is about 11seconds. But if I delete all the nodes as shown below, it takes 27seconds. Are there any other fast ways to delete the nodes, while keeping the calculation time low? (Refresh all memory of a particular function, except the return value?)

```
for(int k=1; k<size-1; k++){//freeing memory
        for(int m=1; m<size-1; m++){
            TEMP1=ARSquare[i][k][m].next;
            while(TEMP1!=NULL){
                TEMP2=TEMP1->next2[j].next;
                while(TEMP2!=NULL){TEMP3=TEMP2; TEMP2=TEMP2->next; delete TEMP3;TEMP1->next2[j].next=NULL;}//delete initial corners
                TEMP4=TEMP1->next2[j].next2;
                while(TEMP4!=NULL){TEMP2=TEMP4->next3;while(TEMP2!=NULL){TEMP3=TEMP2; TEMP2=TEMP2->next3; delete TEMP3;TEMP4->next3=NULL;}
                    TEMP2=TEMP4; TEMP4=TEMP4->next2; delete TEMP2; TEMP1->next2[j].next2=NULL;}
                TEMP3=TEMP1; TEMP1=TEMP1->next; delete TEMP3; ARSquare[i][k][m].next=NULL;}}}
```

Comment: Could you describe what kind of tree you are attempting to replicate? As well as providing a declaration for the ARSquare object?

It's somewhat hard to comprehend the function of your code-snippet without understanding what a single "ARSquare" consists of.

Comment: The correct answer here is to rethink how the memory gets allocated in the first place. Instead of making a bazillion allocations, make fewer allocations, for an entire vector of objects, for example. So that, in the end, there are fewer memory blocks to delete.